# VSCode ModuleNotFoundError in Anaconda Environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

In VSCode whenever I use my conda env I cannot import packages in the terminal.

```
(base) nicomane@nicholass-air ~ % conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/nicomane/anaconda3

(base) nicomane@nicholass-air ~ % python --version
Python 3.11.5
(base) nicomane@nicholass-air ~ % python3  
Python 3.12.2 (v3.12.2:6abddd9f6a, Feb  6 2024, 17:02:06) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

In the bottom right panel in VSCode for "Select Interpreter" it indicates I am using the 'base' environment with path ~/anaconda3/bin/python.

I have double checked and numpy is indeed installed in the base environment of Conda.

Looking for any assitance,

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about VSCode, but in your shown output, `python3` is not the same executable as `python`. They are different versions, and would have different modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python version shown in the lower right corner has nothing to do with the python interactive terminal you open directly in the terminal. They may or may not be the same environment.

If you want to use the python version in the lower right corner. Please use `Run Python File` to execute the script file. If you want to use it in a terminal. first you need to know exactly which environment you are using and then install `numpy` for the corresponding environment. you can print the current interpreter path using the following code.

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```